# Jest can't find AbortController in node v16.13.0

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I am using Jest to run my tests. After an upgrade to Node v16.13.0 (the LTS version) from v12, I got the following error:

> ReferenceError: AbortController is not defined

Whereas running the code manually with Node worked fine.

I upgraded all my packages to the newest versions during the upgrade to v16. I had been using a polyfill for a mock AbortController because I was using Node v12 before the upgrade. Node v16 comes with its own AbortController, so I removed the polyfill. I am using TypeScript 4.4.4, in case that's relevant (this is not a TypeScript error).

This error did not occur with the polyfill.

It seems that when Jest runs it is not using the same environment compared to when I manually run my app with Node.

I tried the following:

- Make Node v16.13.0 the default version using nvm
- Remove all other versions of Node installed except v16.13.0
- Run `console.log(process.env)` at the start of the test and check what Node version is being used -> All references to Node had that same version: 16.13.0.

I've been at this for hours and it seems nobody on the internet has had this problem. Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After more digging I 'fixed' the issue. Simply **remove** `"testEnvironment": "node"` (inside `"jest": {...}`) from your package.json.

I stumbled upon the option to set Jest's testing environment (https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string), and I noticed my package.json already contained that setting (under `"jest": {...}`) and it was set to: `"testEnvironment": "node"`. According to the docs, however, it's the default, so I didn't think anything of it.

Hours later, in a ditch effort of desperation I decided to remove it... And voilà, it solved the problem.

Apparently setting the `"testEnvironment"` configuration to the same thing as its default changes Jest's running environment, which is very counterintuitive and confusing to me.

Edit: This is caused by Create React App. I compared an empty repo with only jest installed with a CRA repo, which comes with jest. Changing the test command to `jest` and adding the configuration above triggers the issue. If you use the default `react-scripts test` command, CRA will not run the tests and give you a big red error that they don't support the `"testEnvironment"` setting.

Comment: It's an interesting finding, I expect it to be Jest bug or some quirk on your side that was magically fixed with config change. I don't see how testEnvironment could cause this, considering that it already defaults to "node" (only in last Jest version), and `global.AbortController` is already available in Node 16. If you can reproduce it, consider posting an issue in Jest repo.

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks for the suggestion! I've updated my answer. Considering this is a CRA issue, do you think I should post an issue there instead of the Jest repo?

Comment: Likely needs to be published in CRA first then. Also may want to try a repro on different machine. This may be local problem, I have no explanations for this except that a script that uses AbortController was evaluated with Node < 16 due to a mess with nvm versions. Even if tests originally run with Node 16, some processes could use another Node version, although I'm unaware of conditions under which this could happen

Comment: I've tested it on one of my friends' machines and they get the same result. I've posted an issue on the CRA repo. I'll update this issue if I learn more